# XenServer 6.5 - cannot create Ubuntu 10.04 guest

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, xenserver, xencenter

I have had Ubuntu 10.04 guest VMs running in XenServer 6.2, both 32-bit and 64-bit without problems. 
After having upgraded to XenServer 6.5 a while back I now need to create a new VM which is running Ubuntu 10.04 to support some legacy app.

I am trying to create that VM from XenCenter, with the parameters 2 CPU cores, 4096 MB RAM, 32 GB disk space, network settings left at default.

However, the VM never starts. XenServer attempts to create the VM, provisions it and creates the disks, but the initial boot does not complete so the actual OS installation never occurs.

The error shown is below. 
I can create other types of VMs, CentOS, Ubuntu 14.04 without problems. 
But Ubuntu 10.04 never works after numerous attempts with varying parameters.

I cannot find any reference to this problem in Citrix docs, and Google turns up nothing. Any ideas?

```
2016-11-27 09:54:38,411 WARN  Audit [12] - Operation failure: VMStartAction: XenServer2: VM 7ded18bb-d14d-5093-dcb1-914edee453fe (OVDAS2): Host 5895b93d-88c8-4ae1-aea5-4950b9b5782b (XenServer2): Starting
2016-11-27 09:54:38,411 DEBUG XenAdmin.Actions.ActionBase [12] - Internal error: xenopsd internal error: VM = 7ded18bb-d14d-5093-dcb1-914edee453fe; domid = 72; Bootloader.Bad_error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/eliloader", line 1153, in ?
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/eliloader", line 1143, in main
    handle_first_boot(vm, img, args, other_config)
  File "/usr/bin/eliloader", line 872, in handle_first_boot
    kernel, ramdisk = debian_first_boot_handler(vm, repo_url, other_config)
  File "/usr/bin/eliloader", line 739, in debian_first_boot_handler
    fetchFile(vmlinuz_url, vmlinuz_file, pv_kernel_max_size)
  File "/usr/bin/eliloader", line 323, in fetchFile
    raise ResourceNotFound, source
__main__.ResourceNotFound
```